# Using a javascript function in a html code

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use a javascript function in a html code.

The only thing that came up on my mind is that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
<input type="file" ... onchange="fileSelected();" />
```

Is there other way to do that?

Comment: Be more specific. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The best way is not to IMO. Use the DOM and add event listener _in JavaScript_. Markup <-> Logic

Comment: That is how you run javascript in html, why not do this?

Comment: Douglas Crockford weeps every time someone uses inline JavaScript!

Comment: use addEventListener. Don't mix HTML with JS too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to give your `<input>` an `id` and attach the click handler with javascript:

```
<input type="file" id="file_picker" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var file_picker = document.getElementById('file_picker');
    var file_picker_change = function() {
        // do some things
    }
    if (file_picker.addEventListener) {
        file_picker.addEventListener("change", file_picker_change, false);
    } else {
        file_picker.attachEvent('onchange', file_picker_change);
    }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" />

        $('#myfile').change(function(){ 
    fileSelected(); 
    });
```

Comment: Note: Don't forget to include jQuery!

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten.

Comment: How about a newer version than 1.5? :P

Answer (score 0):

You can

1) Add external javascript files as you posted here.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>`

2) You can add script parts inside document using:

`<script language="javascript">`
`your script here`
`</script>`

3) You can add script code inline like your second example

`<input type="file" ... onchange="fileSelected();" />`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it.  Make sure this javascript is after the DOM has been loaded and parsed.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

javascript

```
var objInput = document.getElementById("fileinput");

objInput.setAttribute("onchange", fileSelected);
```